# Custom gridview text alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, gridview

I am trying to create Custom Gridview with image and text at bottom but when i scroll down then the alignment gets mismatched because of text
Alignment after scrolling down

[image]

Alignment beforescrolling down

[image]

gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.staritsolutions.apptitude.CategoryImageResize_Adapter
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="150"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: make image size fixed or use weightsum in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try changing height of `TextView` to `wrap_content`:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="150"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:weightSum="3" >

<com.staritsolutions.apptitude.CategoryImageResize_Adapter
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.staritsolutions.apptitude.CategoryImageResize_Adapter
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

For TextView - you can set equal weight is 1 & if your text is not big then set fix weight what you want like .2 or .3
```